# How to Select a substring in Oracle SQL up to a specific character from right?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have string like below,

> ABC_blahblahblah
>   DEFGH_moreblahblahblah
>   IJKLMNOP_moremoremoremore.

I need result like,

> blahblahblah
>   moreblahblahblah
>   moremoremoremore in oracle.

```
SELECT NVL(SUBSTR('ABC_blah', 0, INSTR('ABC_blah', '_')-1), 'ABC_blah') AS output
  FROM DUAL.
```

Above query gives only from LEFT HAND SIDE, But how can I get from RIGHT HAND SIDE.

Comment: What if you have more than one underscore? For example, what do you need from 'aa_bb_cc'?

Comment: @Aleksej it's pretty clear from the title.

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr('ajgdjadg',-4) from dual;

Output:
SUBSTR('AJGDJADG',-4)  |
------------------------
jadg                   |
```

This is what you can do with `SUBSTR` when you specify a negative length.

In your case then

```
select substr('ABC_blahblahblah',-12) from dual;
```

### OR

```
SELECT  SUBSTR('ABC_blahblahblah',-LENGTH('ABC_blahblahblah')+INSTR('ABC_blahblahblah', '_') ) AS output
FROM   dual;
```

Comment: The reason for downvote? I want to correct my error..that's all

Comment: It's ok that you downvote but please let me know the error ...it helps really.

Comment: -4 and -12 hardcoding work if you know well in advance where the character is going to be

Comment: True it's hardworking and after I saw your answer I could see you doing it without using that..but it's unethical at that time to change it...but my solution works and it is what came to mind naturally first...hope your DV is justified..thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...it helps..I will try to give better answer from next time @GurwinderSingh

Comment: @viswanathct.: if it helped select my answer

Answer (score 0):

Using `substr` and `instr`:

```
select substr(col, instr(col,'_',-1)+1) from t;
```

Using `regexp_replace`:

```
select regexp_replace(col,'.*_(.*)','\1') from t;
```

Using `regexp_substr`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, '[^_]+$') from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr('ABC_blahblahblah',instr('ABC_blahblahblah','_')+1) output from dual;
```

### output

blahblahblah